# CGContextDrawTiledImage display black background when over a certain size

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

a complete novice with Swift and SpriteKit so please be gentle.

I am developing a simple game, at the moment it is nothing more than a game world and a player that just moves down until it hits the edge of the game world then dies (hey! I'm learning here and getting to understand game physics, etc).

Anyway, I have my background rendering with the following code, I want to create a circle map with a radius of 2000, and the background image I would like tiled to fill the space, the code below creates the tiled background:

```
let coverageSize = CGSizeMake(8000, 8000)
let textureSize = CGRectMake(0, 0, 599, 519)
let backgroundCGImage = UIImage(named: "background")?.CGImage
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(coverageSize.width, coverageSize.height))
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, textureSize, backgroundCGImage)
let tiledBackground = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

let backgroundTexture = SKTexture(image: tiledBackground)
let backgroundTiles = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
backgroundTiles.yScale = 0.5
backgroundTiles.xScale = 0.5

let cropNode = SKCropNode()
let mask = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 2000)
mask.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
cropNode.maskNode = mask
cropNode.addChild(backgroundTiles)
self.world?.addChild(cropNode)
```

Notice the size of the `coverageSize` which I have had to create to cover the size of the circle radius, if I leave the `coverageSize` at apron. 2000 then the background image displays correctly, as soon as I go over 2000 then the background displays as a black color.  If I leave the `coverageSize` down to 2000 then I get the blue background showing between the edge of the texture and the edge of the circle.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? and is there a better way to draw an image tiled within a specific radius?

Answer (score 0):

Just start with a simple Blue image and make sure your crop is working first before moving on to combining the crop and the tile node. Also, while doing a tile in CoreGraphics will work, it will be slow and use a lot of memory. A much improved impl can be found on my [blog post](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post20_spritekit_repeat_shader), you can just do the tiling directly in a SpriteKit shader, and then crop the results. Be sure to crop with white color, crop is a simple 0/1 threshold tests, you should not use a color.